# How to get all required modules from node.js as a single text file or string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to get all files from some require stack and this include all requires inside the required too.

Example:

file.js

```js
require("./b");
require("./c");
//require("./d"); // this is a comment, need to prevent that
```

AST

```json
[{
    path: "absolute_dir/b.js",
    name: "7saf7fs6asf7" // hash
},
...]
```

ouput (with the AST i can get all files by his name and put them in one single file, like a bundler)

```js
require("7saf7fs6asf7");
require("sa8d78as8d7f");
```

I don't know how to do this in a modular logic. PLZ help me :)